# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 Error Flutter

Tags: flutter, range

Can you please tell me what's the issue with my code and how to avoid showing that red screen error in my app?

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following RangeError was thrown building ChatMessage(dirty):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

My Code:

```
import 'package:crypto_app/models/users.dart';
import 'package:crypto_app/pages/login.dart';
import 'package:crypto_app/services/firestoreservice.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    FriendlyChatApp(),
  );
}

final ThemeData kIOSTheme = ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  primaryColor: Colors.grey[100],
  primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
);

final ThemeData kDefaultTheme = ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
  accentColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
);

String _name = '';

class FriendlyChatApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FriendlyChatApp({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: ChatScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class ChatMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  ChatMessage({this.text, this.animationController});
  final String text;
  final AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor:
          CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut),
      axisAlignment: 0.0,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(child: Text(_name[0])),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(_name, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                    child: Text(text),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<ChatMessage> _messages = [];
  final _textController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  bool _isComposing = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS //new
            ? BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200]),
                ),
              )
            : null,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                reverse: true,
                itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],
                itemCount: _messages.length,
              ),
            ),
            Divider(height: 1.0),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
              child: _buildTextComposer(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTextComposer() {
    return IconTheme(
      data: IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                onChanged: (String text) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isComposing = text.isNotEmpty;
                  });
                },
                onSubmitted: _isComposing ? _handleSubmitted : null,
                decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                    hintText: 'Mesajınızı Buraya Yazınız:'),
                focusNode: _focusNode,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                child: Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
                    ? CupertinoButton(
                        onPressed: _isComposing
                            ? () => _handleSubmitted(_textController.text)
                            : null,
                        child: Text('Gönder'),
                      )
                    : IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
                        onPressed: _isComposing
                            ? () => _handleSubmitted(_textController.text)
                            : null,
                      ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleSubmitted(String text) {
    _textController.clear();
    setState(() {
      _isComposing = false;
    });
    var message = ChatMessage(
      text: text,
      animationController: AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
        vsync: this,
      ),
    );
    setState(() {
      _messages.insert(0, message);
    });
    _focusNode.requestFocus();
    message.animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (var message in _messages) {
      message.animationController.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is happening because of this line:

```
CircleAvatar(child: Text(_name[0])),
```

You've declared the variable as:

```
String _name = '';
```

You are trying to access the first character of an empty string using the index. To fix the issue set some value to that variable:

```
String _name = 'Random';
```